# Wubi installation stuck after "CPU interrupts Balancing Daemon [OK]"

Tags: wubi, system-installation

I have a Gateway LT4004u with an Intel Atom Dual Core 1.6GHz processor (N2600) with built in GMA 3600 series. When I try to install Ubuntu with the run alongside tool (WUBI) after it dowloads UBUNTU and once I restart the system it goes through the text and all but after it says CPU interrupts Balancing Daemon [OK] or what ever it says it gets stuck. How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After managing booting ubuntu using method below using the lightdm display manager then a permanent solution is the following:

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. 
Steps to install GDM (a display manager much like lightdm):

Open terminal(CTRL+ALT+T) and execute following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

then chose gdm from the list: gdm

```
sudo reboot now
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [intel gma3600: X unable to start](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1069031) This bug has now been fixed, but since the fix isn't on the 12.10 ISO or preinstalled image you'll have to boot with the workaround described in that bug report and then update.

Or simpler, you can install the 12.04 release as that is supposed to be working fine. I'd recommend that anyway.

But if you want to try to fix the 12.10, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after selecting Ubuntu until the Grub menu appears. Then press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit and replace `quiet splash $vt_handoff` with `text`. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

Then login and create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so that it contains:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel GMA3600"
   Driver "fbdev"
EndSection
```

(You can create the file with `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `vi` if you prefer.)

Then start the display manager:

`sudo service lightdm start`

After processing all updates, and some people in the bug report mentioned that they had to manually install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

Then you should be able to remove the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` workaround.

Note: All the above information is taken from the bug report referenced above.